# React - how to make innerHtml inside the react router link to take the width of the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a table where a cell is a link. I am setting html as a text of the link:

```
<TableCell align="left" classes={{root: classes.cellPadding}}>
  <Link className={classes.link} to="/">
    <HtmlFormattedText html={oppgave.oppgave_tekst}/>
  </Link>
</TableCell>
```

The `HtmlFormattedText` component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const HtmlFormattedText = ({classes, html, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <span {...rest} className={`${classes.formattedText} ${classes.root}`} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}></span>
  );
};

HtmlFormattedText.propTypes = {
  html: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const styles = (theme) => ({
  formattedText: {
    '& p': {
      marginBlockStart: 0,
      marginBlockEnd: 0
    }
  },
  root: {
    maxWidth: 200
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles)(HtmlFormattedText);
```

I am trying to set the `htmlInnerText` to have `text-overflow: ellipsis`, if the text is too long. I am not sure how to contain the html inside the cell width. I have already set the `max-width` to both `TableCell` and the `HtmlFormattedText`. But, it is still not working. The link to a codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gd3x6). How can I fix this so that long text ends with ellipsis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` adds ellipsis to the text, hence should be added to the element containing text(in your case, the `<p />` tag).

Try adding below css to you `<p/>` tag. Ellipsis should work.

```
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Now coming to the max-width of table-cell, I don't think table-cell will follow the max-width value strictly. Table and it's child elements has its own way of calculating width, which depends upon it's content.

Answer (score 0):

just add below styles to the paragraph element

```
formattedText: {
    "& p": {
      display: "block",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden",
```

Working example below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-chehs